# ARGUMENTS and OPTIONS with Laravel Illuminate Console Command

Tags: php, laravel, console

It's pretty clear how to create a simple command for the CLI in Laravel and this goes also for creating arguments, but I can't seem to find a simple documentation on how to create options for the CLI.

I want to make it so that the user can add options after the argument.
So for example:

php artisan cmd argument -a

php artisan cmd argument -a -c -x

How do I implement such a structure in the class below?

**Updated code**
There are indeed a few possible solutions. It was actually quit easy.

```
class cmd extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'cmd {argument} 
                           {--s : description}
                           {--x : description}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     * 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

       $var = $this->argument('argument');
       $options = $this->options();

       new Main($var,$options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of posible solutions for this, but I prefer to add optional arguments and if they exist do determinate actions with the `?` that means argument can exist or not, plus `*`  this means can be more tan one, like this:

```
class cmd extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'cmd {argument} {-extra*?}';


    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     * 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

       $var = $this->argument('argument');
       if($this->argument('-extra')) {
         //do things if -extra argument exists, it will be an array with the extra arguments value...
       }

       new Main($var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There a whole doc section dedicated to creating commands from scratch and it's well documented. Look through it.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan

If you need to learn from examples then have a look here into all the laravel's built in console commands.

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console
```